# React recharts pie chart problem with labels

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, recharts

I am using Class components in React and recharts library for showing recharts.
I get data from parent component, format it in the child and everything works fine:

[image]

The problem is when I am resizing window, labels disappear:

[image]

I read that it is a problem with animation and I can fix it by just changing `isAnimationActive={false}` but what if I would like to leave the animation and fix this? I tried changing component to functional one, add React.memo, even added `data={[name:'test', value: 1]}` as a static data value but also didn't work. Any solutions?
By the way I cannot understand why this issue was found on 2017 and still not fixed... what is wrong with the authors.

Comment: Once I also faced the similar issue, I fixed by creating custom label. I know isAnimationActive={false} don't work with this.

Comment: I have custom label but I have still this problem

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm assuming you've extended `React.Component` in your class - I can't confirm this as I don't have your code.

Be sure to extend `React.PureComponent` in your class instead of `React.Component`. This should fix the issue.

On the recharts documentation examples, you can see that all components extend `React.PureComponent`: https://recharts.org/en-US/examples

What appears to be happening is that `React.Component` is triggering renderings of the component that have not been accounted for in the recharts library, so `handleAnimationEnd()`, the function that displays the labels, is not being called.

You can read more information about the cause of the issue here: https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1083